# Does "App Picker" exist on iOS when using deep/universal linking?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I need to solve a following problem on iOS platform, based on android functionality.

So whats the story?
Soon we will have custom URL scheme, standardised on a national level that multiple independent companies will need to support/handle.

But there is a problem if the user has more than one installed application that handles that kind of scheme.

**On android in that case, OS platform itself presents to user an "app picker" dialog, so that customer can choose with what application he wishes to open that URL/scheme.
Unfortunately on iOS there is no such functionality, first installed application that is registered for that custom scheme is always the one that handles it.**

So my question is: Am I missing something? Is it possible that iOS is missing that kind of basic functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, `URL/scheme`should be setted specially in iOS , you can not open other application by the Picker the same with Android.

However , you can have a try with customing a popup view contained other App Icon image . Then when you click one image , will invoke the `Open Url` method to the special App .I think this should be a **workaround** in iOS.

Such as bellow code by using [DisplayActionSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#guide-users-through-tasks) to open other App ：

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet("ActionSheet: Open which App?", "Cancel", null, "Twitter", "Facebook");
    Debug.WriteLine("Action: " + action);
    switch (action)
    {
        case "Twitter":
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("twitter://user?user_id=userid"));
            break;
        case "Facebook":
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("fb://page/page_id"));
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

*Note* :You also can custom pop-up View with Image and Label ,code just be a sample guide .